# Split a string and get the second last comma

Tags: javascript, arrays, split

I have a string  `"Fred/Jim/Rob/"`
What I needed is I need the split the string till last and also avoid the last `/`.

I have tried with:

```
for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
var input = ["Fred/Jim/Rob/"] 
var X = input.split("/",);

----some other code---
}
```

In that case, my loop is running till last `/`, So I want to just avoid last `/`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider using `.match` instead - match non-`/` characters with a regular expression:

```js
const str = "Fred/Jim/Rob/";
const result = str.match(/[^/]+/g);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply remove the last `/` and split,

```js
let str = "Fred/Jim/Rob/"
let str2 = "Fred/Jim/Rob"

let newStr =(str)=> (str.endsWith('/') ? str.substr(0,str.length-1) : str).split('/')


console.log(newStr(str))
console.log(newStr(str2))
```

Answer (score 1):

You might also split on a forward slash `/` and [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) the empty entries afterwards using Boolean.

```js
const input = "Fred/Jim/Rob/";
const result = input.split("/");
console.log(result.filter(Boolean));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try following :

```
words = "Fred/Jim/Rob/".split('/');
words.pop();
console.log(words);
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to use `split` method:

```js
let input = "Fred/Jim/Rob/";
let [fred, jim, Rob] = input.split(/[ / ]/);
console.log([fred, jim, Rob]);
```

Answer (score 0):

try something like this:

```
var input = ["Fred/Jim/Rob/"];
var slices = input.split("/");
console.log(slices[slices.length-1]);
```